# extract xml attribute from stylesheets

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the sample xml sheet below and I want to get all the attributes of the `transitLine`, `transitRoute` and `stop` elements with the stylesheet below, but I get a wrong output.

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE transitSchedule SYSTEM "http://www.matsim.org/files/dtd/transitSchedule_v1.dtd">

<transitSchedule>
    <transitStops>
        <stopFacility id="1" x="-53196.450154726146" y="-3755010.0058102254" />
        <stopFacility id="1.1" x="-53196.450154726146" y="-3755010.0058102254" />
        <stopFacility id="1.2" x="-53196.450154726146" y="-3755010.0058102254" />
    </transitStops>
    <transitLine id="1001">
        <transitRoute id="1001_0">
            <transportMode>bus</transportMode>
            <routeProfile>
                <stop refId="180" Offset="00:00:00"/>
                <stop refId="58" Offset="00:03:00"/>
                <stop refId="152" Offset="00:05:00"/>
            </routeProfile>
        </transitRoute>
        <transitRoute id="1001_1">
            <transportMode>bus</transportMode>
            <routeProfile>
                <stop refId="190" Offset="00:00:00"/>
                <stop refId="58" Offset="00:03:00" />
                <stop refId="153" Offset="00:05:00"/>
            </routeProfile>
        </transitRoute>
    </transitLine>
    <transitLine id="10011">
        <transitRoute id="10011_0">
            <transportMode>bus</transportMode>
            <routeProfile>
                <stop refId="29.2" Offset="00:00:00" />
                <stop refId="202" Offset="00:04:00" />
                <stop refId="113" Offset="00:07:00" />
            </routeProfile>
        </transitRoute>
        <transitRoute id="10011_1">
            <transportMode>bus</transportMode>
            <routeProfile>
                <stop refId="29.2" Offset="00:00:00" />
                <stop refId="191" Offset="00:04:00" />
                <stop refId="187" Offset="00:07:00" />
            </routeProfile>
        </transitRoute>
    </transitLine>
</transitSchedule>
```

style.xsl

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        transitLine,transitRoute,routeProfile,links
        <xsl:for-each select="//transitLine">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@id,'&#xA;')"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="//transitRoute">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',@id,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="//stop">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',@refId,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

current output:

```
transitLine transitRoute routeProfile   
1001            
             1001_0     
             1001_1     
             10011_0        
             10011_1        
10011           
             1001_0     
             1001_1     
             10011_0        
             10011_1
```

expected output:

```
transitLine"    transitRoute    routeProfile
    1001"       
                  1001_0    
                                  180
                                   58
                                  152
                  1001_1    
                                  90
    10011                         58
                                  153
                 1001_0 
                                  29.2
                                  202
                                  113
                 1001_1 
                                  292
                                  191
                                  187
```

Comment: What is your current output and what would be the "correct" output?

Comment: @JLRishe I have edited the question to show the outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason that your script failed it that you always (in each `for-each`
loop) take **all** tags of particular name (from the whole source file).

This "take all" approach is OK only for the most outer loop.
For nested loops you should take only **child** elements of the current element.

The script should contain three increasingly nested loops:

- The most outer - for all `transitLine` elements.
- The next - for child `transitRoute` elements of the current `transitLine`.
- And the most nested - for `stop` elements of the current `transitRoute`.
  This time however the *XPath* expression should contain `.//`,
  because `stop` elements are not direct children of the current `transitRoute`.

And the last thing: The printed text has no required leading spaces,
but includes unnecessary commas.

So the whole script should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>transitLine  transitRoute  routeProfile&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//transitLine">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('    ', @id,'&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="transitRoute">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('                ', @id,'&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select=".//stop">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('                               ',
            @refId,'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It gives the required output.